# Configure network interfaces for sip trunk

Tags: networking, routing, sip

I have a Debian 9.5 server that I'm trying to use as a PBX server with a sip trunk, this machine has two network interfaces, one pointing to LAN another one pointing to my sip provider. This is the configuration:

```
iface LAN inet static
    address 192.168.1.247/24
    gateway 192.168.1.254
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254

allow-hotplug SIP
iface SIP inet static
    address 172.xxx.xxx.xxx
    netmask 255.255.255.252
```

And a SIP server with IP: 172.xxx.xxx.xxx

What I want to do is route all incoming trafic from my LAN that targets to my SIP server to it.

I was trying adding this to SIP interface

```
post-up ip route add [MySipServerIP] dev SIP src 192.168.1.0/24 table mgmt
```

Another try:

```
post-up ip route add [SIP ip] dev SIP src 192.168.1.0/24 table mgmt
```

What is the right way to set this route?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89840/discussion-on-question-by-juan-pablo-gomez-configure-network-interfaces-for-sip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well finally the work is done.

First:  Interface LAN was configured by installer itself, then it add mask /24 that must be removed.

```
iface LAN inet static
    address 192.168.1.247/24
    gateway 192.168.1.254
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254 

allow-hotplug SIP
iface SIP inet static
    address 172.xxx.xxx.xxx
    netmask 255.255.255.252
```

Was modified  to:

```
iface LAN inet static
    address 192.168.1.247
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.254
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254 

allow-hotplug SIP
iface SIP inet static
    address 172.xxx.xxx.IP
    netmask 255.255.255.252
```

Then at /etc/rc.local must add two static routes

1. This route sends all trafic to LAN through LAN interface

   ```
   route add 192.168.1.0 gw 192.168.1.254
   ```
2. This route sends all traffic to my sip server through SIP interface

   ```
   route add [SIP SERVR IP] gw 172.xxx.xxx.GW
   ```

This all done the work.

**Note:**

172.xxx.xxx.IP is the Ip assigned by telecom provider

172.xxx.xxx.GW is the gateway assigned by telecom provider

[SIP SERVR IP] is the Sip server ip assigned by telecom provider.